# 504 (Gateway Timeout) error when proxying in Angular app

Tags: angular

I am trying to setup angular app to work with 2 different localhosts.

I've created a `backend` folder in project root and added `echo.php` file in it. In project root, I've also created proxy.conf.json with the follwing content:

```
{
  "/backend/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false

  }
}
```

I try to fetch the echo.php with:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/backend/echo.php').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);      
    });
  }
```

Starting the Angular app:

```
ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

In browser console, I am getting an `504 error Gateway Timeout`. In Terminal, the error sounds a bit different:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /backend/echo.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:80 (ENOTFOUND)
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Can you point me in the right direction? 
I can access the file on non-angular (running on port 80) server directly with this url: http://localhost/backend/echo.php.

EDIT:

echo.php:

```
<?php
echo "data from php";
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem related to Angular if you get an error when consuming your backend directly. You'll have more luck tagging the question as `php` and including your PHP code and relevant configuration instead of the Angular code. (Are you using some PHP framework? include that as well)

Comment: I am not getting any errors when accessing the resource directly using http://localhost/backend/echo.php. Error is only thrown when proxying from localhost:4200 to localhost:80

Comment: I just tried your code and it works on my machine. When you say `"In Terminal, the error sounds a bit different"`, are you using curl to call your server from the terminal or you mean the message logged by `ng serve`? Could you post the command you use if it's curl? Also, which system/container are you running this on?

Comment: it is an error message when ng serve is used. I am not sure what you mean by system/container.. I am running it on OSX:) in the mean time, I realized that adding "changeOrigin":true fixed this issue (not sure why it isnt mentioned in the docs). But guess what, the problems didn't stop there :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613765/php-script-not-getting-executed-when-run-with-proxy-server-in-angular . Is configuring Angular really supposed to be this painful?

Comment: For me, it hasn't been painful at all, things ran out-of-the-box with the ng CLI, but I'm in Windows, maybe those are bugs specific to OsX? as your code worked well for me.

Comment: Okay, the problem was finally fixed. This time for good :D changeOrigin didn't really fixed it. I changed the GET link and actually serve static PHP files without knowing it. Proxy was never even used after I changed the resource link. The real issue was with specifying the target in proxy.conf.json. I posted an answer below.

Comment: I think this is a specific issue when using OSX/MacOS, it's happened to me too and the solution below worked after trying everything else I could find

Answer (score 24):

After many, many hours I found the real issue. It stems from specifying target in proxy.conf.json. This is correct:

```
{
  "/backend/*": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

And this is not:

```
{
  "/backend/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

This could be connected with not being capable of executing `ng serve` on its own.

```
ng serve
```

command returns an error:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

This is an old issue and I never got to the bottom of this error. Instead, I just used `ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0` to get around it.

It would be awesome if someone could explain why this works. My `/etc/hosts` file has the following content:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.1.1      router.hm
127.0.0.1 My-MBP # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
```

Comment: 4 hours of trying to solve exactly the same problem, I've come the the fact that I have to run `ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0` on OSX to make this work! Surprised there isn't more info out there about this!

Comment: I found I had a typo in my proxy.conf.json. Thanks leading me towards a solution

Comment: similar issue i ran into while trying proxy api calls for a python serve. using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost fixed the issue. thank you and upvoted!

Comment: Using http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

proxy.conf.json file

```
{
    "/api/*":{
    "target" : "http://127.0.0.1:1234",
    "changeOrigin" : true,
    "secure" : false
    }
}
```

changing proxy.conf.json file and at the same time running php development server as 127.0.0.1:1234 instead of localhost:1234 solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this error: 504 (Gateway Timeout) error when proxying in Angular app

You might be surprised by this answer and I found that I made a very silly mistake and overlooked the proxy target. The mistake was a simple typo in the proxy.json.

Target was set to: locahost instead of loca**l**host

As silly as it may sound I spent more than an hour on this and defintely my eyes need some checkup.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sure.. added more context

Answer (score 1):

I do not why but order of url in `proxy.conf.json` is really important.

For example, if you put your url `'/api/person/getPerson'` after `/api`, then I got the same error as OP:

```
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:800/',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        agent: agent,
        onProxyRes: onProxyRes
    },
    '/api/person/getPerson': {
        target: 'http://localhost:88888/',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/api/person/getPerson": ""
        },
        onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
          res.json(
            [
              {
                "id": "id",
                "name": "Jon Skeet"
              },
            ]
            );
            return res;
        }
    }
```

However, if this url `'/api/person/getPerson'` will be put before `'/api'` then it works fine:

```
    '/api/person/getPerson': {
            target: 'http://localhost:88888/',
            secure: false,
            logLevel: "debug",
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
              "^/api/person/getPerson": ""
            },
            onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
              res.json(
                [
                  {
                    "id": "id",
                    "name": "Jon Skeet"
                  },
                ]
          );
          return res;
        }
    },
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:800/',
        secure: false,
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        agent: agent,
        onProxyRes: onProxyRes
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried proxying with `ng serve`, but what worked for me is having the backend app in the root directory and the angular part in a subdirectory under a folder name `view` or `front-end` or whatever you like. Check here [Launch angular 4 from Hapi js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515887/launch-angular-4-from-hapi-js/47515938#47515938) for a similar issue but with nodejs. If you have any questions feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score -3):

I have used timeout with retry for the respective get/post http call for resolving this 504 error like 
retryWhen(error => error.delay(5000)).timeout(900000)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please elaborate how this will help fix the issue. If you are posting some code, use the code blocks.

Comment: For a http call if we get 504 error for gateway timeout , instead of throwing exception instantly, we can use retryWhen to fetch the response after some delay.