# PHP script not getting executed when run with Proxy server in Angular

Tags: php, angular

I am using this code to fetch data from another localhost server running simultaneously as the "Angular localhost":

```
const req = new HttpRequest('GET', 'http://localhost:4200/echo.php', {
  reportProgress: true,
});
this.http.request(req).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But I am getting an error:

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 at Object.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHt…, text: "↵echo "{'data':'inSrc'}";"}
```

Contents of echo.php:

```
<?php
echo "{'data':'inSrc'}";
```

If I access this resource in browser, it echoes as expected, but then accessed with http.request(), it complains about the syntax error. I guess this means that the PHP file never executed. What should I do about it?

Comment: Try adding a header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo` so your browser knows what to expect.

Comment: thanks for taking your time. same error is thrown if this header is used

Comment: Hmm. Are you running a webserver that can server php files? `text: "↵echo "{'data':'inSrc'}";"}` kind of looks like it cannot.

Comment: Also its not valid json.. `{"data":"inSrc"}` is. You should instead be using `echo json_encode(['data'=>'inSrc']);`

Answer (score 0):

Your client shouldn't be seeing that word `"echo"` in the response, your backend's PHP should execute it and print `{'data':'inSrc'}` instead.

So there are two possibilities:

1. Your backend is sending an error message in a HTTP 2xx response that includes the word `echo`
2. Your backend is serving your PHP file as if it were a text file.

In either case, you can debug this problem by adding this to your request: `{responseType: 'text'}` like this:

```
this.http.request(req, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

That instructs Angular to not parse the response (which is where your error comes from). So you'll have the opportunity to see the response from your backend to understand what's wrong with it.

Here is the relevant documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

**BTW:** If you are using Chrome, you can use the Developer's Tools, "Network" tab to inspect the response from your server before Angular has the opportunity to see it, that's what I use to debug this kind of situations. You'll need to open the "Network" tab before the HTTP request is made.

**BTW#2:** It's been years since I touched PHP, but in my time I needed to add `?>` at the end to make a full PHP block, yours opens with `<?php` but never closes.